# Javascript place problem or another thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, rss, lightbox

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Urunler.aspx.cs" Inherits="Urunler" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />

<link href="rss/example_ticker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="rss/jquery.zrssfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="rss/jquery.vticker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox/css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<style type="text/css">

...
...
...
<td style="background-color: #808080">
                                            
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#ticker1').rssfeed('http://www.xxxxxxx.com/map.asp').ajaxStop(function () {
     $('#ticker1 div.rssBody').vTicker({ showItems: 3 });

   });
   });
</script>     
                                                                                                             
<div  id="ticker1" >                                                         
</div>
```

I have two scripts: lightbox and rss. Lightbox script works very well in mywebform1 but rss feed doesn't work. How can I solve that?

PS: on the other hand, my another webpage(mywebform2) in the same website has only rss feed and works very well.

Comment: What do you mean by 'rss feed dont work' ?
Also, please include the rendered HTML instead of the asp.net source

Comment: Does your other page that works also load both Prototype and jQuery frameworks?

Comment: why are you using 2 js framework!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely experiencing conflict between the jQuery and Prototype frameworks you loaded.

Either choose which one you want to use (arguably the better solution), or consult this documentation for how to use both together.

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into issues because you're using both Prototype and jQuery on the same page.  It's highly unlikely that this is the best thing to do. I'd recommend just using jQuery and getting rid of Prototype and Scriptaculous ... there are plenty of ways to get what you need done in jQuery alone.